# If I select 'lock device' in Android device manager, will it affect scheduled alarms?

Tags: alarm, android-device-manager, lost-phone

I have left my phone at my girlfriend's house - it's definitely there according to the location feature in Android device manager.

There is an alarm set for really early in the morning, which it would be great to turn off.  If I select 'Lock device', will this have any effect on the preset, scheduled alarm set in the stock clock/alarm app?

Presumably I could definitely stop the alarm if I selected 'Erase device' but this seems like a drastic option!

Comment: Why not just get ahold of your girlfriend and have her find the phone and turn off the alarm. To answer your question, no, locking the device will not have any effect on alarms or other services, it just locks the screen with a special passcode.

Comment: Thanks for that - she'll already be asleep, so was seeing if there was a way to not need to wake her!

Comment: Locking device is only to prevent access to it, it does not impact alarms or scheduled operations say like Titanium Backup or any other synch scheduled. So, your alarm will ring - up to you to wake her and inform our let the alarm wake her up :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No,no effect on the preset, scheduled alarm set in the stock clock/alarm app because the alarming processes are generally given in a 'Android Service', that is a background process. Lock screen will not affect a background process.